# What is the correct approach to modify react state from inside a socket listener?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a real-time chat app with react native and socket.io and trying to update the messages state array with new data whenever the 'chat message' event fires. But inside the callback function, the value of messages is always an empty array, however, the desired behavior is that it contains the list of previous messages and just pushes the new data in the array.

I can't figure out what's going on here. I think maybe it's because of the callback function's closure. I wanted to know what is the correct way to modify state variables from inside the event listeners?

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const _onMessage = (data) => {
    console.log(`${client.id} : ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
    console.log('new message');
  };

  const connect_socket = () => {
    client.connect();
    client.on('connect', _onConnect);

    client.on('disconnect', _onDisconnect);

    client.on('chat message', (data) => {
      console.log(`${client.id} : ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
      console.log('new message');
      console.log(messages); // this is always empty despite it being the state variable
      const temp = messages.slice();
      console.log(temp);
      temp.push(data);
      console.log(temp);
      setMessages(temp);
    });
  };

  const remove_socket = () => {
    client.disconnect();
    //   client.removeListener('connect', _onConnect);

    //   client.removeListener('disconnect', _onDisconnect);

    //   client.removeListener('chat message', _onMessage);
    client.off('connect');
    client.off('disconnect');
    client.off('chat message');
  };
```

Comment: where did you invoke _onMessage method?

Comment: Oh my bad. It's not used anywhere. While debugging I replaced it with the callback function on the 'chat message' event. Shouldn't have added it in question.